# LiveData observer never getting removed between shared ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I'm becoming crazy.

I have a SharedViewModel shared between FragmentA and FragmentB, which contains a LiveData:

```
class SharedViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _searchParameters = MutableLiveData(SearchParameters())
    val searchParameters: LiveData<SearchParameters> = _searchParameters
}
```

and I observe this liveData in the onViewCreated() of my FragmentA (only, not in FragmentB):

```
viewModel.searchParameters.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { searchAndFilter ->
   Log.d("FragmentA", "observed searchParameters in FragmentA")
   mSearchAdapter.updateSearchParameters(searchAndFilter)
}
```

My problem is that **the observer never gets removed when FragmentA is destroyed:**

If I navigate to FragmentB (using Navigation Component), then from FragmentB I do findNavController().popBackStack(), I would expect FragmentA to have removed my observer in `onDestroyView()` (which I have confirmed is called correctly when navigating to FragmentB). But this isn't happening. So when I navigate back to FragmentA, the LiveData is being observed another time, and now I have multiple observations of this LiveData. If I navigate back and forth 10 times, my observer has now been registered 10 times and is being called 10 times foe every event.

I have also tried removing the observer manually by keeping a reference to it and doing

```
override fun onDestroyView() {
     super.onDestroyView()

     Log.d("FragmentA", "onDestroyView")
     viewModel.searchParameters.removeObserver(searchParametersObserver)
}
```

But the same problem occurs.

So my question is what is going on, and how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Is the `mSearchAdapter` also a shared field (through VM)?

Answer (score 2):

I created a sample test project at [Github link](https://github.com/xyzwilliamxyz/live-data-navigation-stackoverflow-sample) that goes from `fragmentA` to `FragmentB`. It seems to work correctly, when on `FragmentB`, `FragmentA` stops receiving events and when back to `FragmentA`, `FragmentB` stops receiving events. And `FragmentA` is always reused while `fragmentB` is recreated (see `hashCodes`)

[image]

I think your problem could be caused by something else such as: wrong sharedViewModel config, incorrect navigation configuration on `navigation.xml` or incorrect navigation from A to B. I suggest checking the sample link and see if what you're doing matches it.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that only fragment's view is destroyed, but not the fragment itself.

Check if setting up observers in `onCreate` instead of `onCreateView` would resolve your issue.